# Fake GPS on Blue Stacks?

Tags: bluestacks

I downloaded blue stacks and trying to get a fake GPS program to work.

I tried like 4 different programs now and when I try to launch them they just crash(no clue what the error is nor how to check). Best one so far loads the app up with a black screen where the map should be.

Comment: I have the same problem. Are you using windows 8.1 or 8? What version of bluestacks. I have windows 8.1 with bluestacks 0.9.17... In general a lot of stuff that worked for me in windows 7 doesn't in 8.